# Compositional layout horizontal groups that don't fill all available space

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

Using `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout`, I'd like to achieve a design where row 1 (group 1) contains 1 `.fractionalWidth(0.5)` item (fills half the horizontal space) and row 2 contains 3 items, each `.fractionalWidth(0.33333)` (3 items that fill all the horizontal space). The problem that I'm having is that compositional layout doesn't like leaving extra space at the end of row 1. Do I need to manually compute a trailing inset for group 1? Or is there a less manual approach?

| Current | Intended design |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Here's the code I'm using currently:

```swift
private lazy var compositionalLayout: UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout = {
    let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
      widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
      heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
    let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
    item.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 6, leading: 6, bottom: 6, trailing: 6)

    let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
      widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
      heightDimension: .absolute(100))
    let group1 = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitem: item, count: 2)
    let group2 = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitem: item, count: 3)

    let containerGroup = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(
      layoutSize: .init(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .absolute(200)),
      subitems: [group1, group2])
    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: containerGroup)
    return UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
  }()
```

Comment: Can you add some code to the question, specifically the layout portion for the `UICollectionView`. Then we can assess what the issue is.

Comment: @Owen26 good call - I've added the code that I have so far.